# Print subfolder without parent folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to count the files subfolder from a folder but when trying to see what the path returns, i see that it includes also the path to the parent folder and not only the subfolder paths only. how to i exclude the parent folder from my output? Here is my code

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('data'):
    print path
```

Here is the output.

```
data
data/02062016
data/03062016
data/07022016
data/11252016
data/12042015
```

I don't want the `data` parent folder included which will only return.

```
data/02062016
data/03062016
data/07022016
data/11252016
data/12042015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because path is where you *currently* are. If you just want to print the subdirectories you'll need to do something like this:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('data'):
    for dirname in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(path, dirname))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.listdir('data')`

This will prevent entering subdirectories (like walk does) fyi. And also list subdirectories.